# The 'props' parameter implicitly has a type of 'any'. (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, switch-statement, styled-components

I'm adding the dark and light theme effect, and in all containers it worked, but the background color 'props' in this code is not being recognized and returns as "any".

```
background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.secondary};
```

The project is a task list tool and I made the "Type ContainersProps" to validate that the task has been verified. I believe there is conflict here.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

type ContainerProps = {
    done: boolean;
}

export const Container = styled.div(({ done }: ContainerProps) => (
    `
    display: flex;
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.secondary};
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    align-items: center;

    input {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    label {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: ${done ? 'line-through' : 'initial'};
    }
`
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your issue is that you're mixing two ways of passing props to the styling (you are destructuring `done` from the props in the function being passed to `styled.div()` and then you are passing an additional function to be evaluated as the `background-color`). For custom props, you can look at the [Styled-Component docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props) where you specify your custom type but still use a function to apply it. In your case, that would look like:

```
type ContainerProps = {
    done: boolean;
}

export const Container = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
    display: flex;
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.secondary};
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    align-items: center;

    input {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    label {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: ${props => props.done ? 'line-through' : 'initial'};
    }
`;
```